# Learning table joins in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to wrap my head around normalising tables the code I have put together below is for demo purposes and isn't production. I have created two tables, a `users` table and an `eye_color` table so I can have a one to many relationship between to two.

What I want to do is show the user and their eye colour by name but even trying to return a result is proving difficult for me and I am wondering where I am going wrong I have looked and searched but I learn better from discussion:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users 
        INNER JOIN eye_color 
        ON user.eye_color = eye_color.id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result)  > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['eye_color'];
    }
} else{
    echo 'No results';
}
```

Im not looking for an outright answer I am looking for advice so I can move forward and continue my understanding.

My table structure is like the following:

```
Table name: users
id (PK)
name
email (Unique)
eye colour (FK)

Table name: eye_color
id (PK)
color
```

Comment: You may want a left join instead of an inner join. [This is a good explanation of the different types of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: will there be many possible eye colors for a user? if yes left join you need

Comment: @PeterDarmis Well, each user will be given in this example a single eye colour

Comment: @aynber great resource I have bookmarked it.

Comment: @PeterDarmis - Left join is needed if user may not have eye color at all or has eye_color column value not presented in eye_color table (which is not possible in that case because of FK constraint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. And additionally add back-ticks to your queries. `user` is a reserved [MySQL keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

```
$sql = "SELECT `users`.`name`,`eye_color`.`color` 
        FROM `users` 
        INNER JOIN `eye_color` 
        ON `users`.`eye_color` = `eye_color`.`id`"; // not `user`.`eye_color`

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result)  > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['color'];
    }
} else{
    echo 'No results';
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, so I was actually understanding what I wanted to achieve, thank you so much for spotting that!

Comment: So, with a join like this, is it possible to output the string/varchar of the eye colour by echoing out the eye_color row?

Comment: Now you can @danjbh just fetch the data that you really need from the database, which are user name and color, if you need email too fetch that also... why all `*`?

Comment: I was just testing this using `*` I know this is absolutely not good practise but it was just to fetch results for now so I could understand how to use a join to get the data I need it makes full sense to me I was on the right lines but I clearly made and error. Also, why use the back ticks is that better syntax or whats the benefit?

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems ok, given that `users.eye_color` references `eye_color.id`.
The issue I see in your code is that you're trying to use `$row['eye_color']` to display the name of the color, whereas that would be the ID of the `eye_color`. You should use `$row['color']`.

In general, to debug issues like this, you could do a `var_dump($row)`, so you can see exactly what keys / values the result contains.

```
// ...
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)  > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       var_dump($row);
       //...
    }
} else {
    echo 'No results';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution that makes so much more sense.